# How to test the performance of a database during crash?

Tags: database, crash, resiliency

I am trying to test my database against crash, i.e. to see how does the DB behave during crash.

I realise that it is not an easy task, because it is not easy to crash the database at a `right` point of time. For instance, I want to crash my program when the writing the database reaches to 70%.

"Crash" migh be different things: for instance, power off, or hard drive is removed, or network cable is removed, etc.

I am working on [rocksdb](http://rocksdb.org).

Could you give me some hints?

Thank you very much,

Comment: "Crash" is undefined - what type of "crash" are you trying to test and how?.

Comment: Let's say, I want to turn off the computer (simulating cable plugget out) at this time. Or the network dies. Or the hard disk is removed. I mean, I want to test with different kinds of crash.